# Is there a way to validate IAM roles/access token from my own code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

When making a requests to AWS services such as S3, the client is signing the request using the AWS secret key. when the request arrives to S3, AWS validates that the signing done using the correct AWS secret key.

I wonder if there is a AWS service that I can use to validate the authenticity of IAM roles or access tokens myself.

for example, Let's say I have a backend service with two apis:

```
/users/create
/users/get
```

I would like to use IAM to validate that the client has the correct permissions to create user or get users.
this way I can have one backend service that has permissions to call both this apis. but another service that is allowed only to call `/users/get`

Comment: You could expose the API endpoints to an API Gateway, and use [API Gateway authorization](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/dc413216-deab-4371-9e4a-879a4f14233d/en-US/4-improve-existing-architecture/task1-apigwauth) to have the gateway validate permissions before passing the request along.